# Does Adobe Air supports RTMFP?

Tags: air, flash-builder, p2p, rtmfp

I have developed a peer to peer video conferencing application which runs on browser, now my need is to export the same application as Android App. I tried using Adobe flash builder, it does connects to Cumulus server, but Netgroup events are not fired. Adobe Air has support for RTMFP or any other solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe AIR 1.5 (or later) Supports RTMFP

Comment: [http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WSa4cb07693d123884520b86f312a354ba36d-7fff.html](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WSa4cb07693d123884520b86f312a354ba36d-7fff.html)